# Xbox One UWP File Access

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox-one, xbox-live

In testing my (C# UWP) game worked flawlessly. However, when I deployed to the Microsoft store my game fails on start up. It has been a few days and the Failure log is now populating with data on the Dashboard.

According to the Dashboard I am having a DirectoryNotFoundException in the main constructor. The only file IO that occurs is setting a media element source to a sound.

```
sounds.Source = new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/Sounds/mySounds.wav");
```

In dev activation mode on my Xbox this all worked fine. The PC version in production works fine too. Does any one know if the Xbox in production has access to a sub directory in the Assets folder?

Update:
I have just now been granted access to the complete stack trace. 
[image]

Comment: Could you please confirm that the `mySounds.wav` is correctly packaged? Have you  testing your app with the Windows App Certification Kit?

Comment: Yes I use the app certification kit, and the game works perfectly on PC. Xbox is the only platform with the issue.

Comment: In that case, you may need to contract the store support. Please try to open a ticket [here](http://aka.ms/storesupport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Store Services SDK version 1710 was signed incorrectly by Microsoft, this was triggering the exception. Once I remove the code that is specific to the Store Services the game was running fine again.